# MSBuild Artifactory Plugin build error

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, artifactory

I'm trying to work with MSBuild Artifactory Plugin. I followed the steps from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qV0VqsAOcoU.  I tried building the solution using VS 2015 and TFS, but the build is giving me the following error:-

.artifactory\Deploy.targets(26,5): Error : [Artifactory] Exception from Artifactory Task: Could not extract targetBuilderCallback from Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost
C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-test-TEST_work\4\s.artifactory\Deploy.targets(26,5): error : [Artifactory] Exception from Artifactory Task: Could not extract targetBuilderCallback from Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost [C:\TfsBuildAgents\Agent-test-TEST_work\4\s\Artifactory1\Artifactory1.csproj]
.artifactory\Deploy.targets(26,5): Error : Could not extract targetBuilderCallback from Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost
at JFrog.Artifactory.BuildEngineExtensions.GetProjectInstance(IBuildEngine buildEngine)
at JFrog.Artifactory.BuildEngineExtensions.GetEnvironmentVariable(IBuildEngine buildEngine, String key, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at JFrog.Artifactory.Utils.SolutionHandler.MsbuildInterpreter(FileInfo artifactoryConfigurationFile, ArtifactoryBuild task)
at JFrog.Artifactory.Utils.SolutionHandler.GetMainConfiguration()
at JFrog.Artifactory.Utils.SolutionHandler..ctor(ArtifactoryBuild task, BuildInfoLog log)
at JFrog.Artifactory.ArtifactoryBuild.Execute()

What am I missing?

Comment: ·Could not extract targetBuilderCallback from Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost· What' this use for? Moreover which vserion of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the latest version for this plugin (2.1 available here :  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cd54930-fcb1-49a1-9c23-c35d50587a0c ) ?

Also the new version of the screencast (for the new plugin and Artifactory 4) is available here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUcFFo6a9k4&index=14&list=PLY0Zjn5rFo4PR0MqN1MsqXG-t4izCcuUx

And the official documentation for this plugin is available here : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/MSBuild+Artifactory+Plugin